# How to handle errors of decompressing a tar.gz file

Tags: php, file, zend-framework, tar, gzip

I have this function which decompress a `tar.gz` file, sometimes when the disk space is full, the file is half decompressed and I get uncomplete data, so to avoid that, I check if the free disk space is more than the file size.

**Note**: I am using zend framework v2.

```
use Zend\Filter\Decompress;
public function extractFiles()
{

    $filter = new Decompress(
        [
            'adapter' => 'Tar',
            'options' => array(
                'archive' => $this->File,
                'target' => $this->Path,
                'mode' => 'gz',
            ),
        ]
    );
    $decompressed = null;
    $freeSpace = disk_free_space($this->Path);
    $fileSize = filesize($this->File);
    if ($freeSpace > $fileSize) {
        $decompressed = $filter->filter($this->File);
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Error while extracting the Tar archive');
    }

    return $decompressed;
}
```

My problem here, I'm not sure about that condition if it will prevent the uncomplete data, because the variable `$fileSize` has the size of the compressed file, and its real size after extrcating it is always way too bigger.
That means this condition is not efficient.
Any idea how to enhance the function?

> **::: EDIT :::**

I tried to use the function `zip_entry_filesize()` but I got this :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function zip_entry_filesize()
```

I am using PHP5.